# websocket при отправке сообщения "Unexpected token o in JSON"

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Задача стояла такая: подключиться к websocket для получения сообщений из чата. Протестировал через Postman, все успешно. Подключение прошло, сообщение отправлено, начал получать входящие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пришло время nodejs:

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://api.talkytimes.com/push/457/thpqtmdj/websocket')

const data = JSON.stringify({method:"register",params:{key:"9b104a8d364d2f86ebe51721b78ac493"}})
const str = "{\"method\":\"register\",\"params\":{\"key\":\"9b104a8d364d2f86ebe51721b78ac493\"}}"
const arr = ["{\"method\":\"register\",\"params\":{\"key\":\"9b104a8d364d2f86ebe51721b78ac493\"}}"]

ws.onopen = event => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    ws.send(data) // a["{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1\"}}"]
    ws.send(str) // a["{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1\"}}"]
    ws.send(arr) // Connection: close Reason: Broken framing. Code: 3000
  }, 1500)
}
ws.onmessage = event => {
  console.log(`Message: ${event.data}`)
}
ws.onclose = ({code, reason, wasClean, target, type}) => {
  console.log(`Connection: ${type}`, `Reason: ${reason}`, code)
}
ws.onerror = (event) => {
  console.log(event.type)
}
```

Соединение установлено. Первый входящий получено, но вот при отправке сообщения соединение закрывается без ошибки:
(*контент тот же самый что и с Postman*)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же отправлять просто JSON строку, то прилетает такое вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема, если через Postman все ок, а вот через nodejs или же через react вот такая вот проблема??? 
P.S. Какого-либо доступа к серверу нет

Comment: добавьте код в вопрос кодом а не картинкой

Comment: @nörbörnën ваш ответ мне не помог, там проблема с подключением, у меня подключение успешно, а вот send() делает проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
ws.onopen = () => {
  const registerRequest = JSON.stringify({
    method: 'register',
    params: {
      key: '9b104a8d364d2f86ebe51721b78ac493'
    }
  });
  const data = JSON.stringify([registerRequest]);
  ws.send(data);
};
```

```bsh
$ node src/websocket-2/index.js 
o
a["{\"result\":{\"register\":true}}"]
a["{\"result\":{\"data\":{\"idLiveVideo\":74433,\"idStreamer\":66528806,\"dateStarted\":\"2021-08-12T17:43:20+00:00\"},\"type\":\"live-video_LiveVideoStarted\"}}"]
```